# Retrieving PublicationTarget in Event System Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1

Tags: 2011, event-system

I am working on Event System code and am trying to retrieve the `PublicationTarget(s)` for the current item being published.
The PublishEventArgs has a property called Targets which you would think is a list of `PublicationTarget(s)` but is a list of `TargetTypes`.

I need the `PublicationTarget(s)` for the current item so I can test and make sure the item isn’t already scheduled for that given target and the date as well.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I currently have the following block of code:

```
           private void ProcessComponent(Component component, String processEvent, PublishEventArgs pubArgs, UnPublishEventArgs unPubArgs)
    {
        if (!IsEventSystemActive())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (IsBundle(component))
        {
            Session session = component.Session;
            Publication publication = component.ContextRepository as Publication;
            //Component configComponent = session.GetObject(publication.WebDavUrl + "/Building%20Blocks/Content/System/System%20Configuration.xml") as Component;

            ItemFields cmpFields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
            ComponentLinkField cmpLinkField = cmpFields["Items"] as ComponentLinkField;

            DateField pubDate = cmpFields["PublishDate"] as DateField;
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            date = pubDate.Value;

            foreach (Component linkedComp in cmpLinkField.Values)
            {
                switch (processEvent)
                {
                    case "Publish":
                        foreach (PublicationTarget pTarg in pubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 0, pubArgs.PublishInstruction.StartAt, pTarg))
                            {
                                Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pTarg);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "UnPublish":
                        foreach (PublicationTarget pTarg in unPubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 1, unPubArgs.UnPublishInstruction.StartAt, pTarg))
                            {
                                Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pTarg);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Component bundleComponent = GetBundleComponent(component);
            if (bundleComponent != null)
            {
                ActivityInstance activity = GetActivityInstance(bundleComponent);
                if (activity != null)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("Component is part of Bundle \"{0}\", which is in Workflow \"{1}\". Publishing the item individually not allowed.",
                        bundleComponent.Title, activity.ActivityDefinition.Title);
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is giving me a cast error due to the fact that the PublishEventArgs.Targets contains `TargetType(s)` and not `PublicationTarget(s)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should sort you out:

```
        PublicationTargetsFilter filter = new PublicationTargetsFilter(component.Session);
        SystemManager systemManager = component.Session.SystemManager;
        systemManager.GetPublicationTargets(filter);
```

Comment: This just gets a list of all Publication Targets. How does it help determining the current target you're publishing to?

Answer (score 6):

With some assistance I was able to get the `PublicationTarget(s)`. Turns out I needed to do a little bit of extra lifting to get it working, but here is the Function again with the new code changes:

```
    private void ProcessComponent(Component component, String processEvent, PublishEventArgs pubArgs, UnPublishEventArgs unPubArgs)
    {
        if (!IsEventSystemActive())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (IsBundle(component))
        {
            Session session = component.Session;
            Publication publication = component.ContextRepository as Publication;
            //Component configComponent = session.GetObject(publication.WebDavUrl + "/Building%20Blocks/Content/System/System%20Configuration.xml") as Component;

            ItemFields cmpFields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
            ComponentLinkField cmpLinkField = cmpFields["Items"] as ComponentLinkField;

            DateField pubDate = cmpFields["PublishDate"] as DateField;
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            date = pubDate.Value;

            PublicationTargetsFilter filter = new PublicationTargetsFilter(session);
            SystemManager systemManager = session.SystemManager;
            List<PublicationTarget> pubTargets = new List<PublicationTarget>(systemManager.GetPublicationTargets(filter));

            foreach (Component linkedComp in cmpLinkField.Values)
            {
                switch (processEvent)
                {
                    case "Publish":
                        foreach (TargetType pTarg in pubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            foreach (PublicationTarget pubTarg in pubTargets)
                            {
                                if (pubTarg.TargetTypes.Contains(pTarg))
                                {
                                    if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 0, pubArgs.PublishInstruction.StartAt, pubTarg))
                                    {
                                        Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pubTarg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "UnPublish":
                        foreach (TargetType pTarg in unPubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            foreach (PublicationTarget pubTarg in pubTargets)
                            {
                                if (pubTarg.TargetTypes.Contains(pTarg))
                                {
                                    if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 1, unPubArgs.UnPublishInstruction.StartAt, pubTarg))
                                    {
                                        Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pubTarg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Component bundleComponent = GetBundleComponent(component);
            if (bundleComponent != null)
            {
                ActivityInstance activity = GetActivityInstance(bundleComponent);
                if (activity != null)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("Component is part of Bundle \"{0}\", which is in Workflow \"{1}\". Publishing the item individually not allowed.",
                        bundleComponent.Title, activity.ActivityDefinition.Title);
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Added the following right before the `ForEach` that handles the Linked components:

```
            PublicationTargetsFilter filter = new PublicationTargetsFilter(session);
            SystemManager systemManager = session.SystemManager;
            List<PublicationTarget> pubTargets = new List<PublicationTarget>(systemManager.GetPublicationTargets(filter));
```

Then added the following `ForEach` statments:

```
                switch (processEvent)
                {
                    case "Publish":
                        foreach (TargetType pTarg in pubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            foreach (PublicationTarget pubTarg in pubTargets)
                            {
                                if (pubTarg.TargetTypes.Contains(pTarg))
                                {
                                    if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 0, pubArgs.PublishInstruction.StartAt, pubTarg))
                                    {
                                        Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pubTarg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "UnPublish":
                        foreach (TargetType pTarg in unPubArgs.Targets)
                        {
                            foreach (PublicationTarget pubTarg in pubTargets)
                            {
                                if (pubTarg.TargetTypes.Contains(pTarg))
                                {
                                    if (!IsInPublishingQueue(session, linkedComp.Id, 0, 1, unPubArgs.UnPublishInstruction.StartAt, pubTarg))
                                    {
                                        Publish_UnPublish(linkedComp, unPubArgs, pubArgs, pubTarg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently did something like this:

```
if (args.Targets is IEnumerable<PublicationTarget>)
{
    PublishEngine.Publish(somePages, instruction, args.Targets.Cast<PublicationTarget>());
}
else
{
    PublishEngine.Publish(somePages, instruction, args.Targets.Cast<TargetType>());
}
```

I have to say, as I wrote it, I was wishing for a tidier way. Frankly, the API should allow you to pass in the collection it handed you.

Comment: I agree about a tidier way. The API should allow you to pass in the collection it returns.

Comment: The thing is, that the API needs to support both, because publishing supports both. If you call a Publish method and pass in Publication Targets, that's what the event will have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to know the *current* Publication Target(s) you're publishing to, this simple LINQ should get you going:

```
List<PublicationTarget> publicationTargets = (from XmlNode node in session.GetList(filter) 
                        select (PublicationTarget)session.GetObject(node.Attributes["ID"].Value) into target 
                        where target.TargetTypes.Contains(targetType) 
                        where target.Publications.Contains(context) 
                        select target).ToList();
```