# Need Publication Targets based on the Target Type (for Event System) using TOM.NET API

Tags: event-system, tom.net

I started event system code for my project, where I am getting Target Types for a Publication. Please suggest how to get the Publication Targets based on the Target Type:

My Requirement is : I need to unpublish the component based on the Expiration Date (Metadata field) while publishing the component. I am using following event (PublishEventArgs).

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, PublishEventArgs>(OnComponentPublishPost, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

I am following below snippet code

```
private void OnComponentPublishPost(Component component, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    foreach (PublishingTarget ty in args.Targets)
    {
       string targettype = ty.Id;
    }
}
```

Here I am getting Target type (ty.id). In unpublishing method I need to pass the Publication Target(targets).

```
PublishEngine.UnPublish(items, unpublishInstruction, targets);
```

Please suggest how to get the Publication Targets.

Comment: I think it will help if you edit your question and specify a bit more detail. Like what event are you subscribing to, and why you need the Publication Target?

Comment: One of the answers in [this post](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/635/retrieving-publicationtarget-in-event-system-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1) has the snippet that might help you.

Comment: What TCM version do you use? Starting from 8.1 there is an overload of UnPublish method that takes in target types.